# PHP Pagestructure to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, data-structures

Okey, so this is my problem. 
I have a page structure saved into a mysql db.
Like this:

Page 1
- SubPage 1.1
- - SubPage 1.1.1
- - - SubPage 1.1.1.1
- - - SubPage 1.1.1.2
- - SubPage 1.1.2
- SubPage 1.2
- SubPage 1.3
Page 2
Page 3

The structure can have endless pages and sub pages. All pages have a field called "url" and "childof". "childof" is what binds a page as a subpage of another.

Example:
Page 1 have "url" page-1 and "childof" is empty
SubPage 1.1 have "url" subpage-1-1 and "childof" page-1
SubPage 1.1.1 have "url" subpage-1-1-1 and "childof" subpage-1-1

Hope you get the basic idea.

My problem is to make a loop to get all these pages out in one good array.

To get first line of pages is easy;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `page` WHERE `childof` = ''
  ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $pages[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
 $i++;
}
```

To get second line is easy aswell...

```
for($x=0; $x < sizeof($pages); $x++){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `page` WHERE `childof` = '".$pages[$x]['url']."'
   ORDER BY `id` DESC";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $i=0;
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $pages[$x]['children'][$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
  $i++;
 }
}
```

And offcourse I could go on like this. But to do this without knowing how many subpages there are is not very efficient. So how do I make a loop to retrieve all pages and subpages into an array with a good structure?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you think of using a different data model? Take a look at [Bill Karwin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin)’s [presentation *Models for hierarchical data* ](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution will be to use recursion to retrieve the children of each page. But this can result in a huge number of queries when the number of pages become large, especially if they are nested deeply.

You might want to look at [this blog-entry](http://crisp.tweakblogs.net/blog/317/formatting-a-multi-level-menu-using-only-one-query.html) as to retrieve all pages with a single query and then using a map to access children of a certain page.

Comment: Hum, good link. Seems I need to rethink my idea of storing it in order in an array. I just understood it would only move the problem forward. I think this will do.. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to add that using recursion is not wrong. It directly reflects the structure as it is stored in the database. It is just that you can't (I believe there are exceptions) get the rest recursively with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use recursion to solve this is here some example code of something I did recently to solve a similar task

```
function retrieveFolderChildren($iRoot, &$aChildren, $cMysql)
    {
        if($cStatement = $cMysql->prepare("SELECT folderName, id FROM dir_structure WHERE rootId=? ORDER BY folderName"))
        {
            $cStatement->bind_param('i', $iRoot);
            $cStatement->execute();

            $cStatement->bind_result($sFolderName, $iId);

            while ($cStatement->fetch())
            {
                $aChildren[] = array( "folderName" => $sFolderName, "id" => $iId, "children" => array());
            }

            $cStatement->close();
        }

        foreach ($aChildren as &$aChild)
        {
            retrieveFolderChildren($aChild["id"], $aChild["children"], $cMysql);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So I figured as well. But I still have a problem figuring out to do go about it. How to even start. My biggest problem is how to structure the array on the fly. I want the array to look something like this when its done; $pages[0][children][0][children][0]['id']. That would be a level 3 subpage.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your table , make new field called subcat as INT
1 = true
0 = false

Create ifstatement to look for the value, if yes go to the while loop else, do nothing i guess?